# Not able to add Checkboxlist selected items to String Array

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, checkboxlist

I have dynamically populated data to my checkboxlist from SqlServer data base.. using code

aspx

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server">
</asp:CheckBoxList>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(
        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["testingCS"].ConnectionString);
    cn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select * from tbl_vehicletypes", cn);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr.HasRows) {
        CheckBoxList1.DataSource = dr;
        CheckBoxList1.DataTextField = "typedesc";
        CheckBoxList1.DataValueField = "vehicletypeid";
        CheckBoxList1.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] arr = new string[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < CheckBoxList1.Items.Count; i++)
        if (CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Selected==true)
            arr[i] = CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Value;

    foreach (string s in arr)
        Label2.Text += s + "<br />";
    Label2.Text = CheckBoxList1.Items.Count.ToString();
}
```

I tried using for loop and foreach as well but it didn't work out. The selected data is not getting added to string array..

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
List<string> selectedValues = CheckBoxList1.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
   .Where(li => li.Selected)
   .Select(li => li.Value)
   .ToList();

foreach(string s in selectedValue)
   Label2.Text += s + "<br />";
```

Comment: Im facing issues in the for loop when im tracing using checkpoints.. CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Selected shows false even if the item is selected... out of 8 elements i selected first 2 elements but still it doesnt add to the string array

Comment: post the entire code so we can check the implementation for you. Thanx

Comment: What is the Label2? I don't see it in your code. There is nothing wrong with the button click code I believe. So the only problem is that Label2 is not showing the text. Could you post the code for Label2?

Comment: I just placed a label control.. to display what the data which is copied into the array... at the moment when i run the code. it shows 8 elements in the checkboxlist.. if i select first 2 .. and click the button.. and start tracing it.. if (CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Selected==true) this statement is not getting validated.. for the first 2 ..

Comment: If you want to dynamically change the text as the user selects the values, use JavaScript

Comment: its not the case @isabelHM. what im trying to do is. im trying to populate data from database and add it to checkboxlist. After the user select few listitem. those item are to be added into a string array.. which i want to store into database.. but the problem is the selected item are not being added to the string array..

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, hope it helps!  Just a demo with one item but it'll work for any number of items in your CheckBoxList.  How are you selecting the checkboxes?

```
CheckBoxList cbl = new CheckBoxList();

ListItem li = new ListItem("test");
li.Selected = true;
cbl.Items.Add(li);

Label labelTest = new Label();            

string[] test = cbl.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(l => l.Selected)
                                          .Select(l => l.Value)
                                          .ToArray();

labelTest.Text = String.Join("<br /", test);
```